# Worklight CLI not starting in mac Giving Error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-cli, worklight-cli

Installed Mobile first CLI 7.0.0.0

When I try to open `mfp cli` it is giving the following error

broken cli but I guess 
any fixes available in IBM Fix central
I tried to search but not able to find a fix for this

> > module.js:340
> >         throw err;
> >               ^ Error: Cannot find module '/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/bin/mobilefirst-cli.js'
> >         at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
> >         at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
> >         at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
> >         at startup (node.js:119:16)
> >         at node.js:906:3

Comment: What is the exact build number of the CLI that you've downloaded?

Comment: Where did you download it from?

Comment: downloaded from IBM site itself

Comment: I might be too late to answer, but I saw mobilefirst-cli.js was missing from the expected location. `1. when you unzip, you will see a resources folder and if you look into it, there is another zip file. Unzip the file. in my case mobilefirst-cli-7.1.0-install.zip 2. Copy this directory called mobilefirst-cli. 3. Go to /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI and paste your directory. You will see the missing mobilefirst-cli.js will be there. I think the mac installer is not extracting the files at the right location.`

Answer (score 0):

The file it is reporting as "Cannot find" is a file packaged with the installable. You can cross check your downloaded contents and the installation steps by referring to the information here 
https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/install/#clui

Answer (score 0):

i faced same problem ... when you download CLI Zip from IBM site . first of all you need to `Extract all` not `Run`

like this picture

[image]